# How to catch up a total distance of 187.5 km at a rate of 50 km/h?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I set two trains' distance equal, [the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1067141) is $75t = 125(t - 2.5) \implies t = 312.5/50 = 6.25$ hours.

> To catch up a total distance of 187.5 km at a rate of 50 km/h...

But how I calculate this? $187.5/50$ is wrong, because above I calculated $t = 312/50$.

Answer (score 0):

You are measuring $t$ from the time the first train left.  The linked question asks how long it takes the second train to catch up, so $t$ is measured from the time the second train leaves.  That question got $3.75$ hours and $3.75+2.5-6.25$.  Different question, different answer.

Comment: Hi Ross, I have a general question about the **slope of a line**: suppose that the slope of a line is $m = \frac{2}{3}$ (in units meters/seconds, for example), then is saying "the rate of change is two meters per three seconds" equivalent to saying "the rate of change is two-thirds meters per second" by converting to a *unit rate*?

Comment: @TaylorRendon:  yes, these are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are subtracting $2.5$ time units to the train going at $125$ km/h, instead of adding $2.5$ time units to the train going at $75$ km/h.

If you expand your equation it looks like this:
$$75t = 125(t - 2.5) \iff 75t = 125t - 312.5$$
so solving for $t$ in this last expression would tell you how many hours it would take the train going at $125$ km/h to catch the train going at $75$ km/h, given that the slower train has a head start of $312.5$ km.

The correct formulation would be:

$$75(t+2.5) = 125t \iff 75t + 187.5 = 125t$$

which reduces to $t= \dfrac{187.5}{50}.$ Notice that now the head start is of $187.5 $ km, corresponding to $2.5$ hours of travelling at $75$ km/h.

Intuitively this means that the $2.5$ hours of head start were travelled at the speed of the slower train, not at the speed of the faster train, which is what you would be implying with your original solution.